# Create a SINGLE exe file from python without requiring to reference a picture

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

important thing to note before we begin is that I'm new to Python. Sorry if any of what I write happens to somehow offend you by the sheer ignorance of it.

Here is my code, basically it's a facial detection that asks you to browse an image and runs the detection on it, my problem starts at line 53 (Starting from #window layout):

```py
import cv2 as cv
import os
import sys
from tkinter import filedialog
import PySimpleGUI as sg
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):

    directory = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

Bckg = resource_path("unknown.png")

def Face_recognition():
    original_image = cv.imread(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                                          title="Select a File",
                                                          filetypes=(("PNG images",
                                                                      "*.png*"),
                                                                     ("JPEG images",
                                                                      "*.jpg*"),
                                                                     ("all files",
                                                                      "*.*"))))
    grayscale_image = cv.cvtColor(original_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(directory + '\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
    detected_faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale_image,scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    )
    for (column, row, width, height) in detected_faces:
        cv.rectangle(
            original_image,
            (column, row),
            (column + width, row + height),
            (25, 255, 25),
            5
        )
    resized = cv.resize(original_image,(1920,1080), cv.INTER_AREA)
    cv.imshow('Image', resized)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

#window_layout
path =  directory +'\\unknown.png'
layout = [[sg.Button("Browse")], [sg.Text("Face Detector")],[sg.Image(filename=path)]]
window = sg.Window("Face Detector",layout)
while True:
    event, value = window.read()
    if event == "Browse":
        Face_recognition()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
```

It can only run when it's with the image, so my question is this: How could I make it so the image isn't required and is somehow part of the .exe? Does altering the spec file do anything? After scouring enough I found people editing it but I couldn't for the life of me get it. Here's the spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Recognition.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('data', 'unknown.png')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='Recognition',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

[Here is the image and project directory (unknown.png is the image I use and Recognition.py holds the above code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YJ4d.png)

Is it even possible? It's a university requirement so I imagine it is but it might be vague wording, thank you in advance!

Comment: @Matiiss: That doesn't make the file part of the .exe file.

Comment: @martineau what does it do then?

Comment: @Matiiss: It copies them into the same folder as the .exe (or a sub-folder of it).

Comment: but as it seems the OP is creating a onefile and per the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle): _When you bundle to a single executable, copies of added files are compressed into the executable_

Comment: @Matiiss: I believe so. Using `datas` is for one-folder bundled apps which are different from bundling to a single executable — see this [information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html) about one-folder bundles and `sys._MEIPASS`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the image as base64 once and set it as a variable at the top, then you won't require packaging or distributing the image file.

There's also https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#placing-data-files-at-expected-locations-inside-the-bundle if you don't want to use base64. Basically,

```py
from pathlib import Path
path_to_dat = (Path.cwd() / __file__).with_name("unknown.png")
```

Your Spec file is incorrect. It should be:

```py
datas=[('unknown.png', '.')]
```

Comment: you want them to hardcode the image byte code in their script? and then read it from those bytes?

Comment: @Matiiss yes, see https://github.com/elibroftw/music-caster/blob/master/src/b64_images.py. If the image is exceptionally large, then only would I ship the image as a file. But I would also use the --onedir option, not the portable distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this image never changes and will always be the same every time the user runs your code, then you can include the image in the python source file.

A utility and repo and may be of help is `psgresizer`, published by the PySimpleGUI project.

It will encode your image into Base64 that you paste into your .py file and then can be used by the PySimpleGUI Image Element.

If you paste the encoded string and store in variable named `encoded_image`, then your layout would be:

```py
layout = [[sg.Button("Browse")], [sg.Text("Face Detector")],[sg.Image(data=encoded_image)]]
```

This will remove the need for any external files, at least this specific external file.

There is also a GUI front-end for PyInstaller that may be helpful that is called `psgcompiler`